# How to retrieve a value from a Blockchain using PHP?

Tags: php, bitcoin

I'm trying to retrieve a set of values from a Quark blockchain (Quark is cryptocurrency like Bitcoin).

To those who don't know, the way that the blockchain works is if the given wallet address is QRHb2CTvGnwwrf6GHrxgQcH2tTAUoGhnC2 the blockchain has a way to display how much in total was received (or spent, or balance). Just click on the link below

```
http://176.221.46.81/chain/Quarkcoin/q/getreceivedbyaddress/QRHb2CTvGnwwrf6GHrxgQcH2tTAUoGhnC2
```

and you will see it print 41210004.6588

So what I want to do is:
the value in `http://176.221.46.81/chain/Quarkcoin/q/getreceivedbyaddress/QRHb2CTvGnwwrf6GHrxgQcH2tTAUoGhnC2`
**minus**
the value in `http://176.221.46.81/chain/Quarkcoin/q/getsentbyaddress/QRHb2CTvGnwwrf6GHrxgQcH2tTAUoGhnC2`

and to print the resulting $balance

What I want to do is the to import that value of how much has been pain in 41210004.6588 **minus** 17610004.6588 (how much has been paid out) and to print the Balance on my own website.

How can I do that with PHP? Can someone please help with the code?

Comment: google for PHP cURL. It's very simple, i promise.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen some cURL codes, but couldn't get it to work in my Drupal.  I can't wrap my head around it, that's why I asked here.  Could you provide a PHP code for this case, please?

Comment: Apart from your question - if you are working with currency/money, floating values and integer/string casting, I strongly encourage you to use http://php.net/bc the binary calculator for all calculations no matter how simple they seem, from beginning of your app, since it will save you much later on.

Answer (score 1):

You want an HTTP client. Something that would allow you to fetch data from remote webpages.

You can use (from best to worst):

- A proper HTTP client library, like **[Artax](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax)**.
- **[cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)**
- **[`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)**